# How to install Unity Web Player for TOR browser?

Tags: tor

I want to test my Unity Web app.

I've made an onion site according to [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-hidden-service-tor-site-set-anonymous-website-server/) instruction. (But used Apache instead of Savant).

When I download a unity web player installer through TOR, and install it, nothing happens.

How can I install it? (I understand that it is insecure)

I tried location Firefox plugins folder, but there is no such in Program files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox, neither in current profile in Roaming/.../current_profile.